# JAXB Unmarshalling NullPointerException

Tags: java, javafx, jaxb, unmarshalling

In my program, I have a marshaller and an unmarshaller so I can save an ObservableList data. Saving the list as an .xml with the marshaller works but when I try to load the file, I get a NullPointerException. Here is my code:

```
public void loadPersonDataFromFile(File file) {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(EntryListWrapper.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

        // Reading XML from the file and unmarshalling.
        EntryListWrapper wrapper  = (EntryListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);

        data.clear();
        data.addAll(wrapper.getEntries());

        // Save the file path to the registry.
        setEntryFilePath(file);
}
```

I also have a wrapper:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import adress.view.EntryTableData;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

@XmlRootElement(name = "entries")

public class EntryListWrapper {

    private ObservableList<EntryTableData> entries;
    @XmlElement(name = "entry")

    public ObservableList<EntryTableData> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }
    public void setEntries(ObservableList<EntryTableData> data) {
        this.entries = data;
    }
}
```

This is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(ClassFactory.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create(ClassFactory.java:127)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.startPacking(Lister.java:280)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.startPacking(Lister.java:253)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Scope.add(Scope.java:103)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty$ReceiverImpl.receive(ArrayERProperty.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:597)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:165)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
at adress.view.TableAppController.loadPersonDataFromFile(TableAppController.java:505)
at adress.view.TableAppController.handleOpen(TableAppController.java:412)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

I am not quite sure what the problem is, although I suspect that it may have something to do with the wrapper.

**UPDATE:**
I fixed the error. It was on my own part in that it works when I replace the ObservableList in the wrapper with a List. It also happened that I needed to initialize a Date in my EntryTableData class.

Comment: I don't know the JAXB API, but it's pretty much impossible to see any way your `entries` list can ever get initialized here: the unmarshaler simply doesn't have enough information to create an object (and your code doesn't do it either). `ObservableList` is just an interface, and the only way to create an instance in the public API is via a factory method. If you're expecting the unmarshaler to instantiate this list somehow, it would have to be "told" to instantiate it via a call to `FXCollections.observableArrayList()`.

Comment: @James_D I'm new to java and sorry if it's a nuisance but could you help me, I don't really know how to initialize the entries list so that the unmarshaller can create an object? Or could you help me tell the unmarshaller to instantiate via FXCollections.observableArrayList() as I'm not quite sure how to code that. Thanks and again sorry if my mistake or your instructions were painfully obvious, I'm just new to Java and would like to learn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: can you provide sample of the xml you try to unmarshal?

Comment: To me it looks like the `file` parameter of loadPersonDataFromFile() is null. Can you validate it?

Comment: Which JAXB version do you use, exactly?

Comment: @Boris Unlikely. The problem is in JAXBs `ClassFactory` which is JAXB internals. Apparently JAXB can't instantiate some class for some reason but it's strange to see it failing witn NPE. Debugging into `ClassFactory` should actually solve the mystery.